# Multiple role="radiogroup"

Tags: html, forms, radio-button, radio-group

I'm trying to implement multiple `radiogroups` on the same page. Despite separate `name` and `form` the radio buttons behave as one group - if you click in one group it deselects in other group.

```html
<form id="rg1_label">

  <ul class="radiogroup" id="rg1" role="radiogroup" aria-labelledby="rg1_label">
    <li id="r1" tabindex="-1" role="radio" aria-checked="false">
      <img role="presentation" src="https://picsum.photos/50/50/" /> 1
    </li>
    <li id="r2" tabindex="-1" role="radio" aria-checked="false">
      <img role="presentation" src="https://picsum.photos/50/50/" /> 2
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
<form id="rg2_label">
  <ul class="radiogroup" id="rg2" role="radiogroup" aria-labelledby="rg2_label">
    <li id="r3" tabindex="-1" role="radio" aria-checked="false">
      <img role="presentation" src="https://picsum.photos/50/50/" /> 3
    </li>
    <li id="r4" tabindex="-1" role="radio" aria-checked="false">
      <img role="presentation" src="https://picsum.photos/50/50/" /> 4
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misinterpreted the problem here. First, let us dispense with the term *selected*, it applies to `<option>` elements. Radio buttons can be *checked* or not.

At the moment **none** of your list items can be checked at all.

When you click on one, because they have `tabindex="-1"`, they gain the *focus*.

This means they are the element that the user is currently interacting with. If the user pressed a key, then a `keydown` and `keyup` (and the deprecated `keypress`) event will fire on that element. If they press tab then the focus will move to the next element. To indicate that the element has the focus there is a visual highlight given to it in most browsers.

This is **not** the same as being checked. The `aria-checked` attribute does not change.

`tabindex` allows keyboard interaction, and `aria-` lets you communicate information about the purpose and current state of the element to screen readers and other assistive technologies.  They **don't** turn the elements into real checkboxes.

You need to handle, yourself, with JavaScript, a variety of things including:

- Storing the checked state
- Unchecking the currently checked element when another is checked
- Reading the data when you want to use it for something (like submitting to a server as form data)
- Changing the `aria-` attributes to reflect the updated state

(Possibly some other things, I'm not trying to write an exhaustive list here).

---

Generally speaking, using *real* radio buttons is a much better (and much easier) approach then using non-radio buttons with a bucket of CSS, JS and ARIA to make them behave like real radio buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation! Based on this, I'll real radio buttons instead.

Answer (score -1):

I think I found a solution to your problem. If it doesn't work or if it isn't what you are looking for let me know and I will try to find something else.

```
<form id="rg1_label">

        <ul class="radiogroup" id="rg1" role="radiogroup" aria-labelledby="rg1_label">
            <li id="r1" tabindex="-1" role="radio" aria-checked="false">
                <input type="radio" name="radiobroup">
                <img role="presentation" src="https://picsum.photos/50/50/" /> 1
            </li>
            <li id="r2" tabindex="-1" role="radio" aria-checked="false">
                <input type="radio" name="radiobroup">
                <img role="presentation" src="https://picsum.photos/50/50/" /> 2
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="radiogroup" id="rg2" role="radiogroup" aria-labelledby="rg2_label">
            <li id="r3" tabindex="-1" role="radio" aria-checked="false">
                <input type="radio" name="radiobroup">
                <img role="presentation" src="https://picsum.photos/50/50/" /> 3
            </li>
            <li id="r4" tabindex="-1" role="radio" aria-checked="false">
                <input type="radio" name="radiobroup">
                <img role="presentation" src="https://picsum.photos/50/50/" /> 4
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

Here I instead of putting the list into 2 forms i put it into one but into 2 lists. It would help if you could tell me why you need it in 2 form.

Comment: Please explain your solution as it is not apparent from what you've posted.

Answer (score -1):

Another way you might could fix it is by using Javascript and if statements like if this one is checked then value = such and such. That might work. I still don't understand why exactly you need two forms and not use one?